# Register to ObservableCollection<AnyType>.CollectionChanged without knowing the generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I've one "base" class, in which I want to observe any change made.

For all the properties, I go through a `GetValue<T>()` and `SetValue<T>()`. Then I've a `Dictionary` of backing field, stored with the `CallerMemberName` as key.

When doing a `SetValue<T>()`, I would like that if `T` is an `ObservableCollection<AnyThing>` to register to the `CollectionChanged` event(or unregister the previous value).

Any idea how I could achieve this?

```
public void RegisterIfObservable<T>(T value){
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>)){
        //TODO Register
    }   
}
```

The goal would be to create an object at each insert/remove

```
new UndoableListAddAction<TU>(ObservableCollection<TU> collection, TU addedElement)
```

Comment: What is `T` in this case?

Comment: @PatrickHofman T is the ObservableCollection<TU>(well, it might be, but there is no generic constraint on this)

Answer (score 1):

The `CollectionChanged` event is available through the interface [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), which `ObservableCollection<T>` implements. You can just use that, and get rid of all the checks with `Type` as well.

Comment: That's nice, I didn't know this! My only issue is that in the EventHandler I've to create an instance of a generic class.

Comment: and I need also to use the `ObservableCollection<T>` in the event handler(well, at least an `IList<T>`)

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use plain old `object` and the non-typed interfaces such as `ICollection` (no `<T>`) which `ObservableCollection<T>` also implements? All that reflection code would be just hard to read, and you're losing type safety at some point anyways.

Comment: Well, in this object, I need to do the opposite operation(if it was a remove, I need to be able to call Add, if it was an add, I need to do a remove of it). So I've the feeling I need the type, but I'm open if you have any other idea?

Comment: [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) for instance has both Add and Remove. Another solution which is slightly more type safe would be to make one generic method which does everything, type-safely, and then call that method using generics. Then you have only one type-unsafe part.

Comment: oh? No, the end type in all the sub-object have to be typed. This class will be derivated by hundred of subtypes, for which we want to have the types. At this level we just want to do some "generic" tasks that will work for all the `ObservableCollection<T>` properties

Answer (score 0):

You could have a helper method `public void RegisterObservable<T>(IObservable<T> value) {}`, which you call trough reflection:

```
public void RegisterIfObservable<T>(T value){
    Type type = value.GetType(); 
    // I don't think you can simply use typeof(T) instead of value.GetType() here
    // if the compiler does not know for certain at compile time 
    // whether T will be an IObservable. 
    // And if you DO know that at compile time, then use the alternative solution below.

    if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
    {
        Type genericArgument = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterObservable"); 
        // instead of this.GetType() you could use the type
        // of a helper class where RegisterObservable is located

        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);
        genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[]{value});
    }
}
```

This involves a lot of reflection each time though, Mattis solution would probably be faster, and easier to debug.

---

### Alternative solution:

you probably only want to call `RegisterIfObservable` for an `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, not just any object.

If your method `RegisterIfObservable` can be inside a generic class and you already know the type of the elements, you could do it without reflection:

```
public class HelperClass<TU>
{
    public void RegisterIfObservable<T>(T value) where T: ICollection<TU>
    {
        var obs = value as ObservableCollection<T>;
        if (obs!=null)
        {
           ...
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, unfortunately, I  only know `T` not `TU`. Currently I'm trying a solution based on `dynamic` usage